# Dynamic div content. jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm looking for a method to populate a `div` with content based on which i click.

First of all, I generate a dynamic table like this:

```
    user    name     total hours worked     button(unique id, that i fetch from database)

    user    name     total hours worked     button(unique id, that i fetch from database)

    user    name     total hours worked     button(unique id, that i fetch from database)
```

The info i get is from database, and as for the buttons each one have a different id, the one from the database table, that corresponds to the user.

What i want to do now:

When I click detailed info, to go to another table, and for the user i clicked to make another table, with detailed data. I managed to make the function:

```
public function show_detailed_activity(){

    $string = $this -> detailed_activity(2);

    $string = str_replace("\n", '', $string);

    $function = "
          $('#detailed_table').append('".$string."');
    ";
    $empty = "$('#detailed_table').empty();";

    $this -> javascript -> click('.btn.btn-info',$empty);
    $this -> javascript -> click('.btn.btn-info',$function);
    $this -> javascript -> compile();
}
```

detailed_activity is a function that gives me the string that in html is a table with the data i need, for the user with id that i pass.

But as you can see i just passed '2' to test if it work. So dosen't matter what button with class '.btn.btn-info', I click, my div will have the info of user with id '2'.

How can I make that, when i click button, first to retrieve the id of button, after to call the function that belongs to a `Codeigniter model` and after to pass it to the div ?

Comment: post the html for the table

Comment: output in browser when i call with '2'.

<table class="tg"><thead><tr><th class="tg-031e">Date</th><th class="tg-031e">Number of hours worked this day</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>2014-10-08</td><td>4</td></tr><tr><td>2014-10-25</td><td>5</td></tr></tbody></table>

Answer (score 0):

Add an argument to your function.

```
public function show_detailed_activity(id){
    $string = $this -> detailed_activity(id);
    // ...
}
```

And call it like this, from within click event:

```
show_detailed_activity($(this).attr("id"));
```

Comment: The problem is, on click event i pass a string with the content already built to append. And to call it in click i can't because it won't let me to call a php function from one of models in jQuery.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't noticed this was server side code. You will have to use ajax to fire requests to the server and use the responses on the same page.

Comment: I solved. Not a good way, but i did it by echo'ing the data directly in a var in jQuery, using json encode function.

Answer (score 0):

As per your html you are assigning different classes so you can get all of them like

```
$('.tg tr th')
```

then if you want a particular one you can do something like this(assuming id the id are available through js)

```
$('.tg tr').find('#1')
```

html I used for this is

```
<table class="tg"><thead><tr><th class="tg-031e">Date</th><th class="tg-031e" id="1">Number of hours worked this day</th></tr></thead></table>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: the html is generated dynamically. i don't need to interact with it. my problem is that. i click on a button in first table. that button have an id. with that id i go to database in an table with events. fetch all event with that id, and make the table from them. 

so my problem is. when i click button, first to get it's id, pass to the php function to know what data to get from db to pass to the function that gives me html string. and after to append it.